# What kind of different request and response scopes are there in PHP?

Tags: php

I slightly remember from my age old Java days, that there was an RequestScope object and a Response object. RequestScope contained the POST headers sent from browsers and the GET arguments. Well, it's a few years ago, might be inaccurate.

What kind of scopes for request and response are there in PHP environment? Well I think there's a $_GET and $_POST (sorry if wrong, I'm just a few days new to PHP). Is that the only thing? Where does the output go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works a bit differently in most PHP environments than you're describing from Java.  PHP uses several ["super-global" arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) to contain request, environment and system information: `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_SESSION`, `$_SERVER`, `$_FILE`.

In general, the response is simply the output you write to `STDOUT` as the script processes.  It is possible to use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) to help control what is sent to the client, but there is no native support for a response "scope" or "object".

Answer (score 1):

> RequestScope contained the POST
>   headers sent from browsers and the GET
>   arguments.

FYI, There is a super-global that contains both the $_GET and $_POST. It is $_REQUEST.